# Movie about two kids who find an astronaut in the desert

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi, parallel-universe

The setting is an Earth-like desert. A brother and sister find an astronaut they believe to be an alien, although he's entirely human in appearance (as are they). I don't remember much about the plot, except that the astronaut believes he's an Earth human until he notices the misspelling of "Tucson" as "Two Sun". He then looks up into the sky and sees two suns, finally realizing he's not on Earth.

I've googled, asked Reddit, trawled through IMDb, and searched this stack, but can't find anything even resembling it. It may have been a made-for-TV movie or a straight-to-video movie, and seemed to be aimed at kids/preteens. I don't recall any well-known actors from it.

Probably from the late '80s, early to mid '90s.

I think the astronaut was on a normal mission, thought he crash-landed back on Earth, but was really on the planet with two suns. I can't recall if/how the alternate Earth was explained. The kids, I think, are trying to help the astronaut figure out where he came from. There may have been government involvement-type suspense.

I checked Wiki's list of science fiction films from both the '80s and '90s and got nowhere. I swear I'm not imagining seeing this movie. Also checked all episodes of The Outer Limits, The Twilight Zone, MST3K, and Ray Bradbury Theater...still no hits.

Comment: Did reddit return anything you’ve ruled out? Got a link to the post? What did you rule out? How did the astronaut get to the other Earth? Was it a parallel world and not a different planet? Can you remember anything else plot wise? Does the astronaut get home? Why was he out there? If you remember anything else you can [edit] in the details into your post?

Comment: reddit: no one offered a suggestion. I haven't ruled out anything. Added some more details to the OP.

Comment: [_The Stranger_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(1973_film)) (1973) matches the general theme but I can’t find reference to kids helping the man. [_Doppelgänger/Journey to the Far Side of the Sun_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelgänger_(1969_film)) (1969) is also very similar but different.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Take a wild guess as to which two movies I was *just about* to mention in a comment as probably **not** being the ones Nikki Sevven is looking for. Go on, guess! (Hint: You only beat me by a few minutes while I was still reading Wikipedia entries and stuff to research my facts.)

Comment: I checked The Stranger and Doppelgänger, but they're both too old. Based on the look of the cinematography, I'm fairly sure it was late '80s or early to mid '90s. I've also checked Wiki's "binary stars in fiction" section, and it was not listed there. IMDB came up blank too.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for a movie and not, say, an episode of a series like _The Outer Limits_?

Comment: I'm not absolutely positive, but I remember it being longer than, say, 30 minutes. I believe it was a full-length film, but it may have been a made-for-TV or direct-to-video.

Comment: Tucson is called 'Two Suns' in an online game called "Fallout" , but that's all I know about it.